# Traversing an XML tree in Python

Tags: python, xml

Second try.

So using

```
>>> for node in tree.iter():
...     print(node.tag)
...
```

I get the following.

```
{http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-3/2006/ETM}DCinemaSecurityMessage
{http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-3/2006/ETM}AuthenticatedPublic
{http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-3/2006/ETM}MessageId
{http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-3/2006/ETM}MessageType
{http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-3/2006/ETM}AnnotationText
{http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-3/2006/ETM}IssueDate
{http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-3/2006/ETM}Signer
{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}X509IssuerName
{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}X509SerialNumber
{http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-3/2006/ETM}RequiredExtensions
{http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-1/2006/KDM}KDMRequiredExtensions
{http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-1/2006/KDM}Recipient
{http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-1/2006/KDM}X509IssuerSerial
{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}X509IssuerName
{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}X509SerialNumber
{http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-1/2006/KDM}X509SubjectName
{http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-1/2006/KDM}CompositionPlaylistId
{http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-1/2006/KDM}ContentTitleText
{http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-1/2006/KDM}ContentKeysNotValidBefore
{http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-1/2006/KDM}ContentKeysNotValidAfter
{http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-1/2006/KDM}AuthorizedDeviceInfo
{http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-1/2006/KDM}DeviceListIdentifier
{http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-1/2006/KDM}DeviceList
{http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-1/2006/KDM}CertificateThumbprint
```

On the first line how do I look at the text after DCinemaSecurityMessage? Or any of the other
test that follows the {http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-1/2006/KDM}?

A segment of the actual xml i'm looking at is:

I'm not clear on how i traverse and store certain parts of that info. Do I have to know whether something is a child or a node or can I just right a for loop that looks for an identifier and than stores what it finds after the identifier?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?><DCinemaSecurityMessage xmlns="http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-3/2006/ETM" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
  <!-- Generated by Waimea 0.4.28l (wlib 0.9.53) -->
<AuthenticatedPublic Id="ID_AuthenticatedPublic">
    <MessageId>urn:uuid:0bb31789-de90-4e17-859b-dc771ff97280</MessageId>
    <MessageType>http://www.smpte-ra.org/430-1/2006/KDM#kdm-key-type</MessageType>
    <AnnotationText>CLOUDATLAS_FTR-1_S_EN-EN_51_PRE_2K_20120830_ADC_OV ~ KDM for SM.Dolby256-DSP100-000004d8</AnnotationText>
    <IssueDate>2012-09-28T17:39:53+00:00</IssueDate>
    <Signer>
      <dsig:X509IssuerName>dnQualifier=G4c6KCUZh7AzcyJnMCXbf9GAfAA=,CN=.cc-wm-2336-000020,OU=.cc-ra-1a.s430-2.ca.cinecert.com,O=.ca.cinecert.com</dsig:X509IssuerName>
      <dsig:X509SerialNumber>61638</dsig:X509SerialNumber>
    </Signer>
```

Comment: What is the question exactly? Second caveat?

Comment: There is no 'ThisPartoftheFIle' in your XML sample..

Comment: Sorry, I was just using that as a generic thing to look for.